# assign cmd variable to output of a for do loop

Tags: batch-file

```
net accounts | for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('find /I "computer role"') do echo %%a
```

This line does exactly what I want to know. However, I would like to assign the output of this command to a variable, then reference that variable later in the batch file. Suggestions?

Comment: Same way you assigned the parsed output of the `FOR` command to a variable in your question you asked yesterday.

Comment: yesterday's mess became: (set /p _build=<"C:\Deployments\deploy.ver" & IF "!_build!"=="%_thisVer%" ) so that's working now.... Are you saying that I can "nest" for statements? Because I tried set /p _type=net accoun...... and it doesn't like it.

Comment: usebackq ;-)...

Comment: This was your code from yesterday: `set build=%%F`.  So what do you think you need to do with this code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Cu613UAG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SET` command is used to assign variables.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('net accounts ^|find /I "computer role"') do set role=%%a
echo role=%role%
pause
```